# UTF-8 characters decoded wrong while flowing through kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, utf-8, avro

I have two services written in java.
One is sending data to a Kafka topic and the other one reads it.
Both services use the same Avro serde mapper, which is based on the Jackson library.

The thing is the there are several characters like : "ü", "ß", "ö" etc. that come out on the other side as "?".

When I test it in unit tests everything works fine.

Here is the code for the Serde class:

```
final public class AvroSerde {

    public static <T> Serde<T> serdeFor(Class<T> rootType) {
        try {
            Method m = rootType.getMethod("getClassSchema");
            Schema schema = (Schema) m.invoke(null);

            AvroMapper mapper = AvroMapper.builder().addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                    .enable(StreamWriteFeature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN)
                    .visibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)
                    .visibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE).build();

            return buildSerde(rootType, schema, mapper);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "class definition doesn't contain a getClassSchema() function. is this auto-generated?", e);
        }
    }

    private static <T> Serde<T> buildSerde(Class<T> rootType, Schema schema, AvroMapper mapper) {
        AvroSchema avroSchema = new AvroSchema(schema);

        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerFor(rootType).with(avroSchema);
        ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(rootType).with(avroSchema);

        return new Serde<T>() {
            @Override
            public Serializer<T> serializer() {
                return new Serializer<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
                        try {
                            return writer.writeValueAsBytes(data);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new SerializationException(e);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public Deserializer<T> deserializer() {
                return new Deserializer<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public T deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
                        try {
                            return reader.readValue(data);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new SerializationException(e);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Any one encountered this issue before?
Any idea how to fix it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the same happen with the Confluent Avro serializers?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by confluent. Before I was using a regular object mapper from ׳com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper׳ and I had the same issue.

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-avro.html